# calculating the average frequency of a given value in pandas

Tags: pandas, frequency

I have the following dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN9QA.png)

[image]

how to calculate the average number of flights pr day (3.67 in this case as we have 3 days with the total number of flights of 11. What would be the command in pandas?

Comment: Please, data as text only in your question, pictures make it _VERY_ hard for users to give you a good answer.

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` + `groupby`  get one output

```
df.groupby('Orign').date.apply(lambda x : len(x)/x.nunique())
Out[331]: 
Orign
1    3.666667
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

`transform` + `groupby` assign to all

```
df.groupby('Orign').date.transform(lambda x : len(x)/x.nunique())
Out[332]: 
0     3.666667
1     3.666667
2     3.666667
3     3.666667
4     3.666667
5     3.666667
6     3.666667
7     3.666667
8     3.666667
9     3.666667
10    3.666667
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Sample Data input

```
dict = {'Orign': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'date': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C']}
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I just generated the sample data :-) append with dict

Comment: This gives the mean number of flights per day *per origin*, right? If OP wants to get the mean count of *total* flights per day (between all origins and to all destinations), I think this works: `1.0 * df.shape[0] / df.date.nunique()`

Comment: df.groupby('Orign').date.apply(lambda x : len(x)/x.nunique()) - it gives me 3
df.groupby('Orign').date.transform(lambda x : len(x)/x.nunique()) - it gives also 3
1.0 * df.shape[0] / df.date.nunique() - this gives 3.67 which is right answer;